# Proper Express Request object destructuring

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I have an Express REST API and want to destructure the `Request` object. I use Typescript so I can see `params` is of type `Dictionary<string>`.

```
import { Request } from 'express';

export class UserService {
    public deleteUserById = async ({ params }: Request): Promise<void> => {
        const { id }: { id: number } = params;
    };
}
```

I get an error

> Property 'id' is missing in type 'Dictionary' but required in
>   type '{ id: number; }'.

The `body` for example is of type `any`. But how can I destructure the `params` object properly?

Answer (score 2):

`id` *is* definetly a string. Typescript is right.

Comment: ahh so each value from params is a string and I have to cast it first?